# Обновление последней записи SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Может я плохо искал, но скорей всего просто не понимаю, как обновить последнюю запись?

Возможно указать какой-либо способ передать переменной `upd`  или заменить её на запрос последней записи?

```
String upd = "3";
public void UpdateDB(String score, String lvl, String tryss){
  database = this.getWritableDatabase();
  contentValues.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
  contentValues.put(KEY_LVL, lvl);
  contentValues.put(KEY_TRYS, tryss);
        
database.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, KEY_ID + "= ?" , new String[] {upd});
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, в в Вашем случае можно получить последнюю запись запросом SELECT MAX(KEY_ID) FROM TABLE_NAME

Comment: *как обновить последнюю запись?* А что такое в данном случае "последняя запись"? в таблицах БД никаких первый-следующий-последний нету, таблица - это несортированная куча.

Comment: Чисто теоретически это `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = newvalue ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Crush как  это прописать в java? Не совсем понимаю как и куда вписывать эту команду. Я правда хочу разобраться.

Comment: А у Вас столбец KEY_ID какого типа в базе данных?

Comment: ```integer primary key```   все остальные  ```String```

Comment: Попробуйте тогда так: ... Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null); cursor.moveToFirst(); String upd = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MAX(" + KEY_ID")); ...